# How to sum two numbers using a Userform and output it in a MsgBox?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have created a userform with three textboxes.

The first textbox is for the first number, the second for entering the second number, and the last one is the result.

I have create a button named Calculate.

I have this code for textbox1:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim a As Integer
a = Val(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

and this for textbox2:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
Dim b As Integer
b = Val(TextBox2.Text)
End Sub
```

and I have a button which shows the result

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim c As Integer
c = a + b
MsgBox (c)
End Sub
```

I enter 1 for textbox1 and 2 for textbox2, 1+2 will be 3, but in the MsgBox I 
see 0. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What have you tried? Simple searching on the internet should tell you how to write the VBA code to do this - StackOverflow is more for help when you are stuck, not when you haven't attempted to code it yet.

Comment: @Issun I have updated first post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't assign the values of the boxes to variables (and unless they are global variables, the scope of the variables life is the routine, so the variable will die after the sub() for each is over, so when the command button event occurs, the variables are no longer alive), just reference them directly. Just add this for your command button and it should do the job.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

MsgBox(TextBox1.Value + TextBox2.Value)

End Sub
```

Comment: Of course you can add data validation to make sure they are numbers :) The great thing about forms is the ability to read the values of the parts at any time ^^

Answer (score 1):

declaration of variables must be in general, it shouldn't be under the Sub...

---

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim c As Double
Dim b As Integer

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 c = a + b
 MsgBox (c)

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
a = Val(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
b = Val(TextBox2.Text)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Calculate_Click()
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
a = Val(`TextBox1.Text`)
b = Val(`TextBox2.Text`)
c = a + b
MsgBox (c)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```vba
Dim a As Double
Dim b As Double
Dim c As Double


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

a = Val(TextBox1.Text)
b = Val(TextBox2.Text)

c = a + b

MsgBox (c)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Amith, welcome to SE! When posting answers, be sure to explain what's happening and the benefits of your solution. Also [have a look at the Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see how to properly format code.